# Excel development - OLEDBConnection.Refresh return value

Tags: excel, oledbconnection, vba

I am using the Office 2010 development library to automate Excel to refresh any embedded database queries the workbook may contain.  I am using the following code (Delphi) :

```
myConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery := False;
blnResult := myConnection.OLEDBConnection.Refresh;
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.oledbconnection.refresh%28v=office.14%29) the method should return `True` if the query completes OK and `False` if it fails/cancelled by the user.  However I'm finding that the function always returns `False` even when the query completes successfully.  Any suggestions as to what might be the issue?

Comment: I'm working on something similar at the moment (VBA, not Delphi, though). What I've found is that OLEDBConnection does not update until the execution of my code completely yields. Application.DoEvents doesn't work, Application.Wait doesn't work, the Sleep API doesn't work. But setting a timer (Application.OnTime) Does. The bit I'm still trying to work out is how to resume mid-way through a sub without using far more GoTo than I'm comfortable with...